# Is there any possibility to invoke/integrate existing selenium automation scripts ( C#) in any of RPA tools?

Tags: automation, rpa

We are doing POC in RPA tools, where we have to make use of our existing selenium automated scripts which is done using c#, is there any possibility to invoke the selenium scripts in RPA tool>